# Moving Single Page Application (ASP.NET WebAPI2) with individual accounts

Tags: c#, authentication, iis, asp.net-web-api2

I really don't know what to do, so I'll give it another try on stackoverflow.

I created a project in Visual Studio 2013. I used the given Single Page Application-Template located at Templates/Visual C#/Web/ASP.NET Web Application. For Authentication I chose Individual User Accounts.

After some work my project is finally done and it works fine, when I start it from VS2013.

Now I want to move this project to IIS. I tried simply copy and paste the whole project to wwwroot and created an application in IIS. When I now browse to that page all my css and js is not available, even though all links are relative. Is there anything I have to change in a config file? Routing?

I searched for a solution the last days, but I couldn't find anything. Is there a tutorial or anything else, which could help me to get my project working on IIS?

Additional question: Will I have to change any database sources for my registered users or can I used the databases created within my project?

I hope you can help me! :(

Answer (score 1):

Check if your resource files are publicly accessible. Possibly [related SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18760562/asp-net-4-0-deployment-issue-css-javascript) to your query. 
In Web.config, check

`<location path="~/Resources/Css">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>`

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but this was not the problem. I found out, that I had to add a subfolder to the relative links. Now CSS and JS files are working.

I also added my subfolder to the /Token Endpoint. Now I get an error 500, when I want to log in. It says, that my SQL Server is not found. Has this anything to do with using the local DB of the project? Will I have to change the db for Users? And how can I manage this? I can't find any connection strings? (Sorry, I'm a beginner yet)

Comment: UPDATE: I added the subfolder to all request-URLs (like e.g. api/Account/...) and these Requests are fine now. Only the /Token-Request switched back to 404 Not found...

Comment: I'm also a beginner to Single Page Applications, just learning by doing. Some of the tutorials in the web save the objects in a .mdf file. 

Could you check if you are able to located any such file, and if there is any connection it?

Comment: Thank you so much! :) I already knew about the mdf-File in my App_Data-folder, but I haven't thought, that this file is mentioned somewhere. When searching for ".mdf" I found the connectionstring in my web.config! Till now I was not able to change it to work, but I'm feeling a step closer... :)

Comment: I finally got it! I just had to copy the tables of the local database to my productive database and change the connectionstring in the web.config! Also I had to change the relative URLs of js- and css-files as well as the routes in app.datamodel.js and Startup.Auth.cs  :)

Comment: So to understand, you had to change the web.config and after modifying the relative URLs of .js and .css files, it was up and running?

Glad it worked !! Cheers :)

Comment: I also had to change all the given routes (e.g. /api/Account/Register to subfolder/api/Account/Register) like the relative URLs. And then it was up and running! ;)